# How to fix base64 image download with Uc turdo mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, download

I'm trying to download image using base64 and working fine with desktop browser. The problem is that it doesn't working on 'Uc turbo browser mobile'.

```
function dwnld() {
        var edge = document.getElementById("qrCode").firstChild;
        //  Egde Support
        if(window.navigator.msSaveBlob){
            window.navigator.msSaveBlob(edge.msToBlob(), 'qrCode.png');
        }
        // Chrome and other desktop browser support
        else{
            // var url = document.getElementById('test').lastChild.getAttribute('src');
            var url = edge.toDataURL();
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.download = 'QrCode';
            link.href = url;
            link.click();
        }
```